# Two linux bash cases

Tags: awk

```
ways
ric
ighl
ft
not 
anne 
hope
```

it should looks like:

```
4. ft
3. not

1. hope
```

I used `awk '{print NR  ". " $s}'

Comment: Think about what `$s` means and why it's producing any output. Going forward, please just ask one question at a time. See [ask].

Comment: Why did you edit your question such that the posted expected output now makes no sense wrt our answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) with `tac`:

```
$ tac file | cat -n | tac
     7  ways
     6  ric
     5  ighl
     4  ft
     3  not
     2  anne
     1  hope

$ tac file | awk -v OFS='. ' '{print NR, $0}' | tac
7. ways
6. ric
5. ighl
4. ft
3. not
2. anne
1. hope
```

1) without `tac`:

```
$ cat -n file | sort -k1,1rn | cut -f2- | cat -n | sort -k1,1rn
     7  ways
     6  ric
     5  ighl
     4  ft
     3  not
     2  anne
     1  hope

$ awk -v OFS='. ' '{buf[NR]=$0} END{for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print NR-i+1, buf[i]}' file
7. ways
6. ric
5. ighl
4. ft
3. not
2. anne
1. hope
```

2)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "yesyesyes"} {print; last=$0} END{print last}' file
yesyesyes
ways
ric
ighl
ft
not
anne
hope
hope

$ awk 'BEGIN{prev="yesyesyes"} {print prev; prev=$0} END{print prev ORS prev}' file
yesyesyes
ways
ric
ighl
ft
not
anne
hope
hope
```

Answer (score 0):

1] Used tac to invert the contents of file linewise.

```
awk '{print NR  ". " $s}' filename.txt | tac
```

2] Chained a series of 3 commands.

```
echo "yesyesyes:"; cat filename.txt; tail -1 filename.txt
```

Comment: And 2) how  to make  A new line  to looks  like hope (new  line) hope  instead  of  hopehope

Comment: You can echo a new line right before tail command. But if there's any files that might have a newline at the end already, and you dont want to repeat. Read: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31955

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, if it's a small file, one solution can be

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) print NR-i+1 ".", a[i]}' file

7. ways
6. ric
5. ighl
4. ft
3. not
2. anne
1. hope
```

or with double scanning

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{n=NR; next} {print (n-FNR+1)".", $0}' file{,}
```

with `tac`

```
$ tac file | awk '{print NR".",$0}' | tac
```

or

```
$ tac file | nl -nln -w1 -s'. ' | tac
```

It's not a good idea to have multiple questions bundled in one, so skipping the next one.  Perhaps you should create a separate question for that one.